# how to reduce lines of code in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-controller, switch-case

in my LWC project have a function per button, and I want to reduce lines and functions using a switch for the buttons. all function buttons are equal and i try use a switch, but I don't know how to get a general value to interact with it (in this case it would be the name of the buttons) so that the data passes and the buttons are activated. Another different attempt that I have used has been the this.template.queryAll introducing the id of the div, but nothing

```
 getButtonPiscina(){
    
    //se saca la id del elemento hatml con el que se va a trabajar
    var bPiscina = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="botonPiscina"]');
    //este condicional permite cambiar de true a false los botones para interactuar con ellos
    if(bPiscina){
        if(this.boolPiscina == true){

            bPiscina.variant = "brand-outline";
            this.boolPiscina = false;
            this.deselectButton();
            this.test = this.boolPiscina;
            
            
        }else{
            
            bPiscina.variant = "brand";
            this.boolPiscina = true;
            this.test = this.boolPiscina;
            this.selectAllButton();
        }
    }else{
            this.test = this.testbad;
        }
}
```

Comment: you cannot directly query the ID of elements, as they are dynamically assigned/changed when the DOM is rendered in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by chance looking how to pass data as an event?:

```html
<lightning-button data-name="btn1" onclick={buttonPress} /lightning-button>
<lightning-button data-name="btn2" onclick={buttonPress} /lightning-button>
```

JS:

```js
buttonPress(e) {
    let btnval = e.target.dataset.name;
    if(btnval == 'btn1') { 
        ... 
    } else if(btnval == 'btn2'){ 
        ... 
    }
}
```